# Is there a reverse Hölder inequality for matrices?

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices and let $p,q\in(1,\infty)$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Hölder's inequality for Schatten norms states that
$$
\lvert \operatorname{Tr}(AB)\rvert \leq \lVert A\rVert_p \,\lVert B\rVert_q. 
$$
(See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.6189v2.pdf) for example.) Moreover, equality holds if and only if $\lvert A\rvert ^p$ is a multiple of $\lvert B\rvert^q$. This is similar to Hölder-type inequalities in other vector spaces. For $L^p$-norms, there is also a *reverse* Hölder's inequality (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Reverse_H%C3%B6lder_inequality) for example).

Is there a reverse Hölder's inequality for matrices? That is, if $B$ is invertible, I'd like to know under what circumstances the following holds
$$
\lvert \operatorname{Tr}(AB)\rvert \geq \lVert A^{1/p}\rVert_1^p \,\lVert B^{-1/q}\rVert_1^{-q}. \tag{1}
$$
The proof given on the Wikipedia page doesn't hold for the case of matrices, since matrices don't necessarily commute. However, the inequality in (1) does hold if $A$ and $B$ commute.

Comment: How do you define $\|A\|_p$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. from the paper, it seems that he is using the [Schatten p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm)

Comment: As a partial result, if $p>\frac12 (3+\sqrt{5})\approx 2.618\ldots$ , this for sure can't hold in general. For this, choose $A=B=\operatorname{id}_n$. Then, (1) would read $n=|\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{id}_n)|\geq\|\operatorname{id}_n\|_1^{p-q}=n^{p-q}$. This is obviously wrong if $p-q>1$, which due to $p>1$ is equivalent to $p>\frac12 (3+\sqrt{5})$ as is readily verified.